# List of List of struct not serializing. System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize an object in XML so that I will be able to deserialize it in silverlight. Pasted below is the code.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder);
serializer.Serialize(writer, data); //error here
string xml = builder.ToString();
```

The code is throwing this error for **data**

```
"System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed."
```

The object **data** is actually

```
 List<List<LabelValueTypeGroup>>
```

where LabelValueType is declared as

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public struct LabelValueTypeGroup/* : IEnumerable*/
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ComparisonType? ComparisonType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this.Label;
        yield return this.Type;
        yield return this.Value;
        yield return this.ComparisonType;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is List not serialize-able or what? Why I am doing it this way is because, I want to pass an object from WCF to Silverlight that is resulting from a select query, that would only select the columns found in an xml file. So I have to create a sort of dynamic serialize-able object which could be de-serialized in Silverlight. Javascriptserializer and JSON are not accessible in Silverlight project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably the `public Type Type { get; set; }` field, holding a reference to a RuntimeType instance which causes the error. RuntimeType is not serializable, that is what the error message tells you.